# Primefaces commanbutton calls ajax second time afer 5 minutes

Tags: primefaces

I am having trouble while using PrimeFaces p:commandButton . When I click the button it sends the ajax request, I can see at the log table that request recieved at first click. But if the service does not response in 5 minutes, it send another request so I can see exactly the same request at the log tables.

I can not see any reason to recall the ajax request at my code.

Here is the code. Any help will be appreciated:

```
<p:panel id="mainPanel" style="width:95%;height:90%;">
<p:outputPanel collapsed="true" closable="true" toggleable="true" id="msgPanel" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
    <p:messages />
</p:outputPanel>
<p:outputPanel id="queryPanel">
    <p:fieldset legend="#{cmIaResources['fieldset.queryForm']}" style="width:600px;height:100%;" rendered="#{cmIaQueryBean.renderQueryPanel}">

        <h:form id="queryForm" prependId="false">

            <p:outputPanel id="xxPanel">
                <h:outputText value="#{cmIaResources['queryForm.label.xxText']}" id="name_label" style="width:150px;" />
                <h:outputText value="#{cmIaQueryBean.xx}" id="xx" style="width:150px;" />
            </p:outputPanel>
            </div>
            <p:spacer />


            <p:outputPanel id="yyPanel">
                <h:outputText value="#{cmIaResources['queryForm.label.yyText']}" id="yy_label" style="width:150px;" />
                <p:inputText id="yyID" value="#{cmIaQueryBean.yyID}" maxlength="10" />
            </p:outputPanel>


            <p:outputPanel id="commanBtnPanel">
                <p:commandButton id="queryButton" action="#{cmIaQueryBean.queryCustomerZZ}" value="#{cmIaResources['queryForm.label.queryBtn']}" update=":queryForm :msgPanel :queryResultsPanel :queryPanel" style="float:right" />
            </p:outputPanel>

        </h:form>
    </p:fieldset>
</p:outputPanel>

<p:outputPanel id="queryResultsPanel" style="width:900px;">
    <p:fieldset legend="Sorgu Sonuçları" rendered="#{cmIaQueryBean.renderResult}" style="width:880px;">
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width:610px;">
                <h:outputText value="Arama Kriterleri:" style="width:150px;" />
                <p:tree value="#{cmIaQueryBean.root}" var="node" id="tree" style="width:450px">
                    <p:treeNode id="treeNode">
                        <h:outputText value="#{node}" id="lblNode" />
                    </p:treeNode>
                </p:tree>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </p:fieldset>
</p:outputPanel>
```